# Acessing Flash Symbol instances in Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, instance, symbols

To load a Flash symbol in Flex, I use

```
[Bindable][Embed('xxx.swf', symbol='symbolName')]
private var SWFClass:Class; 
[Bindable]
public var userClip:MovieClip = new SWFClass();
<mx:SWFLoader x="300" y="300" id="userClip1" autoLoad="true" source="{userClip}"  />
```

and it works well!

Now, I would like to load an **instance (occurence) of the symbol** (which has been created and named in Flash)... Is it possible? Thanks very

Answer (score 0):

Tick the **Export for Actionscript** option in the library for the MovieClip you want to access in Flex.
Then, in Flex you can access the class by that name.

Since you are embedding the SWF, I would suggest using a SWC (as you should also get autocomplete support).

Again, set the Export for Actionscript option for the MovieClips you want to access in xxx.swf, and in **Publish Settings** also tick **Export SWC**.
Once you've linked that SWC to your Flex build path, the exported MovieClip should be available as classes.

> Now, I would like to load an instance (occurence) of the symbol (which has been created and named in Flash)

You would nest that instance into a MovieClip exported for actionscript, if it isn't already.

HTH